# Performance for conditionals, creating files, deleting them and others with the Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, optimization

### Introduction

I tried Fedora a while ago and I loved the way the top-left corner worked, so, when I went back to Ubuntu, I changed it to make it behave in the same way.

Then I wrote (and was able to make it work just now) a little script to close active windows with the top-right corner. It was dangerous, so I decided to go a step further and implement it with a couple of "If statements". So, if the top right corner is touched twice in X seconds, it doesn't close the window. I realize that it's touched as I also configured it to press  and "Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed" is set to true in the System Settings>Mouse and touchpad.

### The code

The code needs to be written in 1 line for CompizConfig>Commands>Commands>Command line 0 (and CompizConfig>Commands>Edge Bindings>Run command 0 is "TopRight") The working code is this:

```
xte 'key Control_L'; if [ -f /tmp/fcont ]; then rm -f -r /tmp/fcont; else touch /tmp/fcont; sleep 1; if [ -f /tmp/fcont ]; then xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key F4' 'keyup Alt_L'; rm -f -r /tmp/fcont; fi fi
```

Then I expanded it and gave it comments to make it more readable:

```
xte 'key Control_L';    #Set to "Show position of pointer"
if [ -f ~/.fcont ]; #If file exists
    then
    rm -f -r ~/.fcont   #Delete it   

else
    touch ~/.fcont; #Else, create it
    sleep 1;
    #If it STILL exists (it doesn't if this is executed twice in X seconds)
    if [ -f ~/.fcont ];
        then
        xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key F4' 'keyup Alt_L'; #Close active window
        rm -f -r ~/.fcont;  #Remove the file
        fi;
    fi
```

### Actual question

So the code is perfectly working. But thinking about performance, creating and deleting files might not be fast enough. Then, **Could you recommend a way of using variables instead of files to do this?** (and if you could implement it, it'd be great!). Thought it has nothing to do with OS, I'm looking for the behaviour of $_SESSION['name'] in php if it existed. Obviously, each execution is in a different process.

Also, any other feedback about this would be appreciated. Use it if you like it.

### Extra Info

[Xte](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte)

[CompizConfig](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why bother? You say "might not be fast enough", but actually, is it not fast enough? What do you observe when you run your script? "Fast enough" is a relative term and I'll bet it all happens in way less than 3 seconds.

Anyway, to answer the question you asked ....

It looks like you're running the same script multiple times in parallel (potentially)? If that's the case then variables won't help you as they're not shared between processes. You could set up some horrible complex system with named pipes, or shared memory, or signalling (killing) existing instances of your script, but the way you have seems simple and safe.

One thing though: you might like to consider placing the files in /tmp: all files in /tmp are stored only in RAM (in many Linux distros) so reading and writing them might be quicker. Really though, all disks are cached in RAM, so it probably makes no difference. If ~/ is a network disk then the RAM cache usually expires after 20 seconds or so, in which case using a local file will definitely be a win.

Comment: You may not make any assumptions about what /tmp is backed by. While on Solaris it indeed is (was?) a tmpfs, this does not hold true in most contemporary Linux systems for example, where a disk is often behind it.

Comment: I believe I said "many Linux distros". However, the OP specifically said Ubuntu which, now I check, does not appear to use tmpfs for /tmp. However /tmp won't ever be a network drive, so it's still better in general. Anyway like I said, I don't believe there's anything to be gained no matter what you do.

Comment: Great answer, I have already looked into pipes and yes, they looked scary. Now I know it for sure. The 3 seconds was just an example. Now I have reduced it to 1 second (it also works) and if xte didn't have a bug (apparently), I'd cut it down to 500ms. The recommendation of moving the file to /tmp was a really good extra. Thank you so much.